# Confusion on where the .testcaferc.json should live

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

According to the TestCafe documentation (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html), the .testcaferc.json file should be located "in the directory from which you run TestCafe". I guess I don't know what that means exactly.

I have created a .testcaferc.json file and put some values in it to see if it would be read from successfully when running tests, but so far, it hasn't been recognized, no matter where I land it.

I have placed it in the node-modules/testcafe folder.
I have placed it in my project location folder.

(I don't know what else to do).

```
{
    "browsers": "chrome",
    "src": ["Desktop", "Mobile"],

    "reporter": { 
        "name": "testcafe-reporter-html",
        "output": "Artifacts/Reports/report.html"
    },

    "screenshotPath": "Artifacts/FailedTestsScreenshots",
    "takeScreenshotsOnFails": true,
    "videoPath": "Artifacts/FailedTestsVideos",

    "videoOptions": {
        "failedOnly":true
    },

    "videoEncodingOptions": {
        "r": 20,
        "aspect": "16:9"
    },

    "stopOnFirstFail": true,
    "skipJsErrors": true,
    "skipUncaughtErrors": true,
    "appCommand": "node server.js",
    "appInitDelay": 3000
}
```

Once the file is placed in the correct place, I am expecting to be able to just type in "testcafe" in my command line and it'll run my project. It should then make screenshots and videos on test failures, skip js errors, etc. It's not doing this.

Just to make sure there weren't issues with my commands, I am able to run my project with "testcafe chrome Desktop"

Answer (score 4):

My problem was not having the most recent version of TestCafe locally. After updating to the latest version, I'm cooking!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify in case anyone lands here, it goes in your project root folder.